# How do I su as normal user without password?

Tags: linux, su

I was wondering if someone can help me with my script.

I have 2 servers. Lets call them Server A and Server B. Server B has a software installed on it that I would like to run from Server A. I'm unable to install the software in Server A.

I have to let users run another software in Server A which will then call a script to call the software in Server B to run a command.

So I created an user called transfer on server A and server B. I allowed transfer to be able to ssh into server B without needing password using authentication keys.

So now from Server A i'm trying to su as transfer, ssh into Server B and run the command.

This works perfectly fine as root. However, when I am myself or any other user, it is asking me for password for the "transfer" user on Server B.

Here is the command sequence:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 su transfer -c 'ssh transfer@ServerB script $1 $2'
```

Comment: It's not asking for the password on B; `su` from nonroot requires the password of the new user _where it runs_, which is A, because Unix was designed as a multiuser system. Try `su transfer -c 'echo hi'` to see this. You can use `sudo` to allow selected users to run this particular `ssh` on A, or you can just give selected users on A the privatekey which allows them to use `ssh` to access _B_ as `transfer`.without having a `transfer` user on _A_ at all.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shell script that executes the remote command:

```
% cat > /home/transfer/exec-remote-sw <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
ssh transfer@ServerB script $1 $2
EOF
% chmod 755 /home/transfer/exec-remote-sw
```

Test this script by running it as the `transfer` user:

```
% /home/transfer/exec-remote-sw  arg1  arg2
```

Now as root, create a Linux group (e.g. `transfer`) then add all the users who need access to this functionality into the Unix group:

```
% groupadd transfer
% usermod -a -G transfer login1
% usermod -a -G transfer login2
...
% usermod -a -G transfer loginN
```

As root, append the following to the `/etc/sudoers` file by running `visudo`:

```
%transfer   serverA = (transfer) NOPASSWD: /home/transfer/exec-remote-sw
```

Test by logging in as one of the users in the transfer group and running:

```
% sudo -u transfer /home/transfer/exec-remote-sw  arg1  arg2
```

To simplify this for your users, have them add the following to their .profile files (or add it to /etc/profile for everyone):

```
alias svrbexec="sudo -u transfer /home/transfer/exec-remote-sw"
```

Then users can type:

```
% svrbexec  arg1  arg2
```

and the remote process should execute with their two parameters passed.